# AngularJS Promise error catching

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code:

```
 angular.module('app.services', []).factory('authService', [
'SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT', 'SIGN_OUT_ENDPOINT', '$http', '$cookieStore', function(SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT, SIGN_OUT_ENDPOINT, $http, $cookieStore) {
  var auth;
  auth = {};
  auth.signIn = function(credentials) {
    return $http.post(SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT, {
      user: credentials
    }).then(function(response, status) {
       return $cookieStore.put('user', response.data);
    }, function(error) {
       return console.log("Incorrect email/password");
    });
   };
  return auth;
}
```

This is my module for authentication. Now I have the following function in controller:

```
angular.module('app.admin.controllers', []).controller('SignInController', [
  '$scope', 'authService', '$state', function($scope, authService, $state) {
    $scope.buttonText = "Login";
    return $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.buttonText = "Logging in. . .";
      return authService.signIn($scope.credentials).then(function(response, status) {
        return $state.go('allPosts');
      }, function(err) {
        $scope.invalidLogin = true;
        return $scope.buttonText = "Login";
      });
   };
}
```

The problem: if I input wrong email/password, I'm waiting for 2 error callbacks - from the first 'then' from the second one, but I catch the first error callback (I can see console log) and after it THE SUCCESS callback executes! (return $state.go('allPosts')). Why? The Response from the server is 401 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is, that you catch the error in the "app.services" and dont "bubble" the problem to higher tiers.

```
angular.module('app.services', []).factory('authService', [
'SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT', 'SIGN_OUT_ENDPOINT', '$http', '$cookieStore', function(SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT, SIGN_OUT_ENDPOINT, $http, $cookieStore) {
  var auth;
  auth = {};
  auth.signIn = function(credentials) {
    return $http.post(SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT, {
      user: credentials
    }).then(function(response, status) {
       return $cookieStore.put('user', response.data);
    }, function(error) {
       console.log("Incorrect email/password");
       return $q.reject();  //here is the important one.
    });
   };
  return auth;
}
```

Or completely miss out the error handler.

```
auth.signIn = function(credentials) {
        return $http.post(SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT, {
          user: credentials
        }).then(function(response, status) {
           return $cookieStore.put('user', response.data);
        });
       };
```

If you catch the error and return a value within the error, following promises dont know about the occured error.

Comment: Ok Thanks. But why I don't need to 'bubble' success to higher level? Should I do it only for errors? Thanks.

Comment: By returning a value within one of the callbacks in then, you basically bubble the success

Comment: TBH the official doc about $q should contain this information, but i didn't find it yet. I did discover it by myself (the hard way). https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 2):

Since the auth service is returning the promise returned by `then` function, in the first error callback you need to return rejected promise.

You can do it in this way:

```
auth.signIn = function(credentials) {
    return $http.post(SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT, {
      user: credentials
    }).then(function(response, status) {
       return $cookieStore.put('user', response.data);
    }, function(error) { 
       console.log("Incorrect email/password");
       return $q.reject(error);   // return a rejected promise;
    });
   };
```

Also remember to inject `$q` into your service, for this to work.

The promise returned by `then` is resolved with the return value of success and error callback functions.
If you do a standard return, you will always land up on the success path.
When you return `$q.reject` you are returning a promise that is eventually rejected. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) on $q.

You can also throw an exception from error callback in the service and get the same result.

Comment: why I don't need the same ($q.reject) for success callback? Does AngularJs do it automatically?